# My select element doesn't get populated with model data

Tags: javascript, sapui5, model-binding

I'm writing a small OpenUI5 application. I would like to attach a model (list with key/text values) to a `sap.m.Select` element (drop-down box).
However, regardless of whether I use static data for the model or fetch the data through ajax, the select element remains empty, no drop-down is displayed. I thought I had followed the examples/tutorials but I can't see what the problem is.

index.html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Q Ui5 POC</title>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
      data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
      data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
      data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
      data-sap-ui-async="true"
      data-sap-ui-onInit="module:de/xx/qpoc/index"
      data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{ "de.xx.qpoc": "./" }'
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body id="content" class="sapUiBody"></body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
], function (XMLView) {
  "use strict";

  XMLView.create({
    id: "qpocMainView",
    viewName: "de.xx.qpoc.view.App",
  }).then(function(oView) {
    oView.placeAt("content");
  });
});
```

App.view.xml:

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="de.xx.qpoc.controller.App"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  displayBlock="true">
  <layout:VerticalLayout>
    <Select
      enabled="true"
      editable="false"
      forceSelection="false"
      items="{
        path: '/clientList',
        sorter: { path: 'text' }
      }">
      <core:Item key="{key}" text="{text}" />
    </Select>
  </layout:VerticalLayout>
</mvc:View>
```

App.controller.js:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
], function (Controller, JSONModel) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("de.xx.qpoc.controller.App", {
    onInit: function() {
      var viewData = {
        "clientList": [
          { key: 'key1', text: 'text1'},
          { key: 'key2', text: 'text2'},
        ]
      };
      var oModel = new JSONModel(viewData);
      this.getView ().setModel(oModel);
    }
  });
});
```

I have removed all non-relevant UI elements and application logic. My understanding is that I do the binding in the `onInit` method of the controller. And that I can reference keys of the JSON structure I'm passing to the JSONModel constructor in the UI element (`/clientList`).

The generated UI looks like this:

[image: Empty select element]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove those two lines in your XML view or set them to `true` (default value):

- `editable="false"` → makes the control non-interactive
- `forceSelection="false"` → none of the options will be selected preliminarily

You do have data bound. It's just the settings that prevented them from displaying.